# SQLAlchemy group_concat ordered values

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I want simulate the behaviour of `collect_set` in SQLAlchemy (using MySQL connector). i.e. group A `1,2,3` would be the same as `2,1,3`. I have the following code:

```
res = db.session \
    .query(T1.col1.label('col1'), func.group_concat(T1.col2.distinct()).label('col2_group')) \
    .group_by(T1.col1) \
    .all()
```

However, by default SQLAlchemy does not order the values in the group, so duplicates may occur.

Is there any way to simulate `collect_set` behaviour?

Comment: Don't you mean "by default MySQL does not order the values in the group"? Please add the DB in question in the question and tag appropriately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately SQLAlchemy has official [aggregate ORDER BY support for Postgresql only](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.aggregate_order_by). You can still express it in other dialects using the [generic `op()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.Operators.op) operator function, though a bit hackishly:

```
func.group_concat(T1.col2.distinct().op("ORDER BY")(T1.col2))
```

which would compile to something like

```
group_concat(DISTINCT t1.col2 ORDER BY t1.col2)
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I use MySQL.

Comment: The solution is for *other* dialects than Postgresql and hence the hackishness. You'd express the same for Postgresql as `func.string_agg(aggregate_order_by(T.col.distinct(), T.col))` or so. You could also implement GROUP_CONCAT as a custom [registered function](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/functions.html#sqlalchemy.sql.functions.GenericFunction) and a compiler for it.

Comment: Well, got the args wrong for string_agg, but the point still stands.

Comment: One thing to note: if you want to order by multiple columns, make sure to join them as strings. E.g. `.op('order by')(', '.join(column1.key, column2.key))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `order_by` with `group_concat` with mysql

```
func.group_concat(T1.col2.distinct(), order_by=T1.col2.asc())
```

would be compliled to:

```
group_concat(DISTINCT col2 ORDER BY col2 ASC)
```

Comment: I just tried this in sqlalchemy 1.4.39 and it completely ignored the `order_by` kwarg.

Comment: This used to work in 1.4.x (not sure which exactly), but stopped working in 2.0. See the accepted answer instead.